# No logro poner quion en valor de un array

Tags: php, wordpress

Tengo un array asociativo el cual quiero que los elementos que tengan varias palabras en vez de tener espacios esten juntos con un guion

```
$options_variant = array_change_key_case($options_variant,CASE_LOWER);

// Esto me devuelve $options_variant
array(6) {
  ["stock"]=>
  string(25) "14PT Printed 1 Side (4/0)"
  ["size"]=>
  string(7) "3.5 x 2"
  ["qty"]=>
  string(2) "50"
  ["coating"]=>
  string(10) "No Coating"
  ["round corners"]=>
  string(2) "NO"
  ["turnaround"]=>
  string(17) "Next Business Day"
}
```

En ese array esta "round corners", ese elemento lo quiero poner asi "round-corners"

Answer (score 1):

La forma más fácil es usar la función `str_replace` que permite reemplazar un caracter o caracteres por otros, por ejemplo.

```
$string = str_replace( ' ', '-', 'round corners' );
```

En el primer parámetro le pasamos el caracter a buscar, en este caso un espacio vacío, en el segundo por cual lo remplazaremos, en este caso un guión y por último con qué string debería hacerlo.

resultado `round-corners`

**Actualización.**

Como lo que se quiere es modificar la clave del item se podria hacer de la siguiente manera.

Primero creamos un array vacío, luego recorremos nuestro array con datos, obtenemos la clave y la convertimos con `str_replace` y luego llenamos nuestro array vacio con nuestras claves modificadas, por ejemplo:

```
$array = array(
    'stock'         => '14PT Printed 1 Side (4/0)',
    'size'          => '3.5 x 2',
    'qty'           => '50',
    'coating'       => 'No Coating',
    'round corners' => 'NO',
    'turnaround'    => 'Next Business Day',
);

$new_array = array();

if ( $array ) :
    foreach ( $array as $key => $value) {
        $key = str_replace( ' ', '-', $key );
        $new_array[$key] = $value;
    }
endif;
```

Resultado:

```
array (size=6)
  'stock' => string '14PT Printed 1 Side (4/0)' (length=25)
  'size' => string '3.5 x 2' (length=7)
  'qty' => string '50' (length=2)
  'coating' => string 'No Coating' (length=10)
  'round-corners' => string 'NO' (length=2)
  'turnaround' => string 'Next Business Day' (length=17)
```

Fuentes: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Pero esa funcion sirve para arrays asociativos?

Comment: Te he actualizado la respuesta, revisa si te sirve.

Comment: Si sirve pero encontre una solucion mejor

Comment: Entonces presiona [edit] y actualiza tu pregunta con esa respuesta para compartirla con la comunidad, también agradecería un voto a favor.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución

```
// Ponemos en minusculas las keys del array
$options_variant = array_change_key_case($options_variant,CASE_LOWER);

// Reemplazamos los espacios por guiones a los keys
$keys = str_replace(' ', '-', array_keys($options_variant));

// Agarramos los values del array asociativos
$values = array_values($options_variant);

// Y juntamos los keys editados con los values
$options_variant = array_combine($keys, $values);
```